# Finder constantly not responding/freezing

Tags: finder, macos, crash

**My system**

I've read about a dozen similar questions to this. I'm running a 13" retina MacBook Pro and using El Capitan 10.11.6.

System is generally stable.

```
Model Name: MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro11,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.8 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 4 MB
  Memory:   16 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP111.0142.B00
  SMC Version (system): 2.16f68
```

**The issue**

Annoyingly the same time I went abroad for several months in a region with no Mac stores without taking several flights and unreliable internet access, the system has basically stopped working.

Well, anything to do with Finder doesn't work. Any time you open a new tab or window it freezes (goes Not Responding) in Activity Monitor and Dock. I get spinning beach ball for 10+ minutes but it usually recovers eventually.

Relaunching or Force Quitting doesn't help at all. There is no CPU spike or anything like that.

Other apps freeze/crash/go Not Responding on start too and never seem to recover. Every single time I try to use BetterTouchTools, TextExpander, Excel or uTorrent they cannot run. I suspect it is related to the more fundamental Finder issue. Weirdly, Word will run fine as will Transmission.

Just tried installing Commander One as an alternative. Hang immediately on opening too.

I put some crashlogs on Dropbox if somebody wants to have a look: [CommanderOne](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw4rkfwa4ku4clh/CommanderOne.txt?dl=0), [Excel](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2bzel82xhz3s9yb/excel.txt?dl=0), [uTorrent](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6coyukrul7axnsi/utorrent.txt?dl=0).

**What I've tried**

- booting into safe mode to reset Finder settings
- resetting SMC
- HDD benchmarks and SMART info is fine
- killing Google Drive
- Nothing obvious in system.log
- `mv ~/L*/S*/*finder.savedState Desktop` followed by `killall Finder`

Edit: also tried restoring from several Time Machine backups as far back as November and the symptoms persist. Wtf is this????

**HALP?!**

Comment: All three crashlogs seem to be related to file access. Did you have an external drive (or network share) attached at home (or any time before the crashes started to occur)? Can you boot into safe mode again and run `fsck` on the disk (to see whether it's slowly failing, SMART doesn't help a lot here)?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "System is generally stable"? From your question it seems that the system is far from stable currently...

Comment: @nohillside - yes, I usually do have various network shares that are meant to automatically connect. I thought they would do this gracefully but it seems not as I have now done two Time MAchine restores with the same symptoms. What would be the best way to get around this?

Comment: I use autofs to keep network drives connected as per this guide: http://blog.grapii.com/2015/06/keep-network-drives-mounted-on-mac-os-x-using-autofs/ It does seem that this is the issue but that sounds crazy - especially as it's a laptop, it seems mental that the whole system crumbles when a local network share is no longer available...

Comment: At the moment the network stuff is just a possible cause. Can you disable the automounter (just rename the config file) and reboot?

Comment: If you've restored backups from a time when everything worked; and Safe Boot doesn't alter it, then you're beginning to rule out software altogether, and it is more likely to be a hardware fault of some kind. I would test an external clean system (even on a small 64Gb thumb drive), and see whether that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: @nohillside, which config file are you referring to? I'll try that now.

Comment: @benwiggy, call me out if you want my all my years of computer intuition rule out a hardware issue. Is there a way I can test an external clean system booting off a USB without a osx disk?

Comment: You could try a network boot. see: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/02/25/how-to-start-up-your-mac-in-internet-recovery-mode/  You can then run disk utility, safari, and terminal.

Comment: @historystamp - Given the aforementioned "unreliable internet access" (i.e. not able to download more than a few dozen MiB in an hour, rarely able to hold a connection for more than a few minutes) I don't see that being an option...

Comment: Sorry also forgot to mention "generally stable" means before these issues began...

Comment: You set up the Auto mounter according to the page you‘ve linked to by modifying a config file. Move that away so the auto mounter won‘t start after a reboot

Comment: Having said that I also wouldn’t rule out hardware issues here.

Comment: If you don't already have an installer app, and your internet is flaky, then a clean install might be tricky. (I always keep a thumb drive with an installer volume for emergencies!) Can you go somewhere with better internet - public Wifi? to download an OS X installer app? One other thing you might like to try is testing a new user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How odd. But I solved it.**

Of course, I lost about half my files with the system restores through Time Machine before I worked it out.

[nohillside ♦](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346512/finder-constantly-not-responding-freezing#comment453252_346512) pretty much got it spot on. It was me using `autofs` to mount network shares. Quite why a network share going down or being unavailable means that the entire system is unusable is beyond me. It fact, thinking about it, it's utterly insane.

I wonder if now I have to write some really hacky script to automatically disable `autofs` if it can't connect to the server a few times in a row.

Another thing that I fear will remain an eternal mystery is why various other apps completely locked up and failed to start. Why TextExpander and BetterTouchTool? Why any file manager? *Why Excel but not Word?!*

**TL;DR - how do I fix it?**

Simply deleted the `auto_nas` file with:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/auto_nas
```

I kept the line in `/etc/auto_master`

Answer (score 0):

Can you add 'nofail" like what fergaljd did?
This is his post, and I also given some suggestion that you might want to try. 
[Login problems with Automount and SMB shares](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355392/login-problems-with-automount-and-smb-shares/358532#358532)

Comment: I'll give it a go but I'd like to know what "soft", "noowners", "nobrowse", "rw" do exactly before trying it. I can't find any resource that actually explains this.

Comment: You can type `man mount` in `terminal`. Scroll down to the bottom of that page, you can further drill down to open manual for `mount_smbfs` for example. Some of the command might only work for NFS but not SMB for example. You can take a look this [website](https://ss64.com/osx/mount.html) for online manual, but you can always type it in the `terminal` for latest version.

Comment: There's nothing I can see in any of the man pages about ,many of those options?

Comment: Okay I tried it and now I can't even get `automount` to work (using the same `auto_master` and `auto_nas` I was previously). When the mount points are mounted they are blank and I can't `cd` into them. I have tried unmounting and rebooting with no effect.

Comment: Do you mind to post your `auto_master` and `auto_nas` setting? It doesn’t mount but it doesn’t make your computer freezes, does it?

Comment: Both are here: https://pastebin.com/j2ZUUf2i No freezes but I haven't taken it outside the local network yet since I added the files back again.

Comment: Hi, I checked your setting. Seems you put `-nofail` in both `auto_nas` and `auto_master`. I think you just need to put it in `auto_master` setting. Anyway, please let us know whether you can connect to your NAS and whether it will cause your Mac to freeze if you bring it outside the local network.. :) Don't forget to restart to make sure new settings are in effect.

Comment: According to the post you linked in your answer, you should put it in both?

Comment: Using my setting, I only put it in `auto_nas`.