# Login problems with Automount and SMB shares

Tags: network, mount, automount

I am using automount to mount a set of network shares on my macbook. My problem is that when these shares are not available, e.g. when I am out of the office using a different network, I cannot login to my mac. The login screen progress bar stays stuck forever (I've let it go well over 12 hours to test).

Currently, my `/etc/auto_master` looks like

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
/-  auto_smb    -soft,noowners,nobrowse,rw
```

Network shares are mounted in the `/etc/auto_smb` map file, which looks like this:

```
/mount/mnt1 -fstype=smb ://<user>@<server>
/mount/mnt2 -fstype=smb ://<user>@<server>
/mount/mnt3 -fstype=smb ://<user>@<server>
/mount/mnt4 -fstype=smb ://<user>@c<server>
```

I am certain that automounter is the source of the problem, because if I comment out the last line of `/etc/auto_master`, I can log in normally no matter what network I am using.

Is there any way I can fix this so that automount fails gracefully on login when the mounts are not available?

I am using macOS Mojave 10.14.3

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem. I follow the exact step described here: http://blog.grapii.com/2015/06/keep-network-drives-mounted-on-mac-os-x-using-autofs/

```
/Users/username/Desktop/Synology  auto_nas
```

Then I created the `/etc/auto_nas` with entry like the following

```
DSVideo -fstype=smbfs ://username:password@nas/video
DSPhoto -fstype=smbfs ://username:password@nas/picture
```

This creates a "Synology" folder on my Desktop with a DSVideo and DSPhoto subfolder which icon looks like a mounted disk as a subfolders.

**It was working flawlessly with El Capitan MacBook Pro**, however when I do the same with my iMac with Mojave 10.14.4, I experienced the same issue similar with yours in which my Mac would locked up just after login while loading Finder in which I could not launch any other applications.

I saw a silver lining after I read your post. It seems that adding `nofail` was able to prevent our Mac from being locked out if it fails to mount.

```
/-  auto_smb    -soft,noowners,nobrowse,rw,nofail
```

Now come to my suggestion for a possible solution. I have been reading forums for many many days. Can you try the following which might help you to mount your network drives?

Have you changed the ownership of your `auto_smb` to root access only?

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/auto_smb
```

Have you followed this recommendation from Apple to disable a security feature so that you can connect without providing additional confirmation? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207112

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.NetworkAuthorization AllowUnknownServers -bool YES
```

Alternatively, you can follow this instruction 
https://gist.github.com/rudelm/7bcc905ab748ab9879ea

So instead of just using the following in your `auto_smb`:

```
/mount/mnt1 -fstype=smb ://<user>@<server>
```

You can add:

```
/mount/mnt1 -fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw ://username:password@<server>
```

Please let me know whether any of this works for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/-  auto_smb    -soft,noowners,nobrowse,rw,nofail
```

Comment: I tried added the `nofail` option to `/etc/auto_master`. This does successfully complete booting, but fails to mount the drives when the network is available. I also do not see nofail in the `man` pages for either `mount` or `mount_smbfs`

Comment: @fergaljd: I never expected that my answer would resolve the issue that's preventing your shares from being mounted! Your question was `Is there any way I can fix this so that automount fails gracefully on login when the mounts are not available?` That's the question I've answered. RE the `nofail` option, it is one of the options in the "fourth field" of `fstab` entries. Unfortunately, Apple has not done a thorough job with their `man` documentation, and it's not listed in the macos version of `man fstab`. So yes, it is not documented by Apple.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand that. My issue with the nofail option is that it always fails to mount the drive when included, no matter if it is available or not. I suspect that is because it is not implemented by Apple's version of fstab.

Comment: Please try reading some documentation before assuming such a thing! The `nofail` option means that a failure to `mount` will NOT STOP THE BOOT PROCESS. That is what you said your problem was. Again, `nofail` WILL NOT CORRECT your `mount` problems. Good luck with your problem.

Comment: OK, I think you are not paying attention to my response. Including `nofail` does allow the computer to boot, but including `nofail` means that the drives are never, ever, ever successfully mounted, even when they should be. Including the `nofail` option means that the automounter is not able to mount the drives ever, even when it should. Basically, `nofail` is not a valid option in any situation, which is highly likely to be the reason it does not exist in the documentation.

Comment: @fergaljd: I was paying attention, but not any longer. Please pick on someone else. I'm done.