# How to store/specify/identify path to different Volumes with the same name in /Volumes?

Tags: macos, network, mount, disk-volume

I am using Synology Diskstation as NAS in my local home network. When I connect my  Mac to the NAS the volume is mounted becomes visible in Finder. In Terminal I can access the NAS folders using `/Volumes/home/some/path...`

Now I have added another Diskstation to the network and when I connect to both they can be accessed using `/Voluemes/home` and `Volumes/home-1`.

When connecting to a remote Network using OpenVPN and accessing another Diskstation it is mounted as `/Volumes/home-2`

**The problem is, that I never know which diskstation is mounted under which path.** The naming depends completly on the order in which the connections are established / the volumes are mounted.

For example I would like to add a Git folder on the VPN machine as remote to a local repository. While adding `/Volumes/home-3/some/path/my.git` as remote is no problem at first, it becomes a problem when the connection is re-established and the volume is now available as `Volume/home` or `/Volumes/home-1`, etc.

**How can this be solved?**

Is it somehow possible to mount / connect different (network) volumes using custom/unique names? For example `/Volumes/LocalNAS/...`, `/Volumes/BackupNAS/...`, `/Volumes/VPNRemote/...`, etc.?

Comment: You could try automount as described in this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/158095/115093) but there may be [issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355392/login-problems-with-automount-and-smb-shares) on Mojave.  What version of macOS are your running?